# Magento fast register on checkout

Tags: magento

I like the idea of doing something similar to this in magento but for the checkout, has anyone come across something similar or know of a git repo that maybe a good starting point?

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fast-registration.html

Comment: well for faster checkout go with one step checkout.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use Template Masters Firecheckout in the settings there is Registration mode I changed that "user is registered during checked without being prompted for password" this was my solutions